Using quarkus.webSockets and in need of a vertx context
When I implement a ServerEndPoint based on the sample provided, I can not call a service returning a Uni. Seems there is no vertx context.
I'd like to use the same service layer I wrote to be reactive. I may be missing something as no one else is I can see is running into this.
thank you
I have refereces ApplicationScope for the class.
